Galileo transformation group
I am reading the book "Mechanics" by Florian Scheck, more specifically on Galileo's transformations.
The author states, in paragraph 1.13 if anyone has the text, that the more general transformation $g$ that maps inertial systems to inertial systems has the following form:
$$\mathbf{r}\mapsto\mathbf{r}'=\mathbf{Rr}+\mathbf{w}t+\mathbf{a},\ \mathbf{R}\in O\left(3\right) ,\ \ \det{\mathbf{R}}=\pm 1 $$
$$t\mapsto t^\prime=\lambda t+s,\ \ \lambda=\pm1$$
My question is: if I also rescaled the axes, as well as rotated them, wouldn't I still get an inertial system?
Thanks in advance.

Mechanis involves an arbitrary MKS-system of gauges for lenghts of point distances in [m], clock reading differences of time in [s] and an arbitrary unit of mass [m].
Its euclidean geometry in the tangent space of velocities rests on the notion of kinetic energy as a symmetric bilinear form
$$T\left(\frac{d\vec  X(t)}{dt}\ , \ \frac{d\vec  Y(t)}{dt}\right) = \frac{m}{2} \ \dot {\vec X(t)}\cdot \dot {\vec Y(t)}$$
In flat space, cartesian coordinates, invariant time $t$, the local euclidean geometry in the tangent spaces at each fixed time extends to a bundle of euclidean spaces of $\mathbb R^3_t$ at constant time along the time axis.
For each particle (another name of an indexed direct sum of such spaces, aka indexed coordinates in the same space), the euclidean form has its own time, scaled by its mass via its kinetic energy.
The invariance group of space, translations,  rotations and mirror symmetries $\mathbb R_3 \times \mathit O(3)\times \pm(t,x_1)$ and time translation/mirror wrt to the quadratic form is unified by introducing a global time scale and length gauge.
Declaring the geometrical square of velocities for all particles wrt to universal time with inedexed coordinates in the same space time is the Galilean space-time, a product of spaces with symmetries of translations $\mathit T$, rotations $\mathit O$, reflections $$\mathbb R_G^4 = (\mathbb R_t \ ,\  \mathit T_t,\pm t) \ \times (\mathbb R_x^3\ , \  \mathit T_x \ , \ \pm x_1\ , \ \matit{SO}(3))$$
Because the kinetic energy form per mass unit transforms by
$$V^2 \to (V+v)^2 = V^2 + v^2 + 2 v\cdot V  $$
the definition of the canonical momentum involves a translation in the momentum space
$$p = m \ V \to p'= \nabla_V \frac{m}{2}\ (V+v)^2 = m \  (V+v) = p + m \ v$$
The canonical free Hamiltonian for a single particle involves a gauge group in momentum space generated by the relative velocity v between a system ($\mathbb R^3$) at rest and its uniformly moving copy.
$$H = \frac{m}{2}(V)^2= \frac{1}{2m}\ (p-m v)^2 $$
$$\dot p = -\nabla_x H =0 \ , \ \dot x = \nabla_p H = \frac{p}{m}-v $$
Any mechanical n-particle system derived from the sum of the kinetic energies of n 'free' particles is a gauge transform of the invariant Galilei world with respect to the following additional gauge transforms
$$\text{time scaling}: \  t \to \omega t:  T(p,p) \to \frac{1}{\omega^2} T(p,p) $$
$$\text{space scaling}: \  \mathbf x \to \ k \mathbf x:  T \to k^2 T(p,p) $$
$$\text{m scaling}: \ m \to  \mu m:  T  T $$
These factors are equal for each point mass particle and can  be discarded in a free theory. With potentials, the scaling gauge factors are absorbed in the coefficients used to build the potentials as functions of the coordinates, themselves subject to length a gauge.
The factros of This gauge transformations
